# What are these type of eyes called (see red hair girl on the left in image)?

Tags: tropes

I'm referring to characters whose eyes are constantly like that (Red hair girl in the picture) and don't change for a brief moment as a depiction of disappointment, most of these characters talk really slow and quietly. Examples include Tooru from A-channel, Renge from non non biyori, Chihaya Megumi from servant X service some of the common traits of the aforementioned characters is the monotonous way of talking and that they nearly never smile [image]

Comment: Which character are you referring to? The one on the left dark reddish brown hair or the one in middle with light reddish brown hair?

Comment: the one on the left

Comment: If the character's eyes are always like that with the flat top, I'm guessing the character is supposed to be very cynical. I suspect though what you're  talking about Tsurime Eyes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TsurimeEyes

Comment: No i don't think either tsurime or tareme cover those, characters that are like thistend to be apathetic and some of them the cloudcuckoolander type, other examples include renge from non non biyori,  Chihaya, Megumi from servant x service and maybe tooru from A-channel

Comment: You should try to update your question a better explanation of what you're after. The example you're using doesn't seem to illustrate the sort character your asking about as an image search reveals that isn't her normal expression. Also, I wouldn't call Renge from Non Non Biyori apathetic or "cuckoo". I'd describe her as serious and determined. Pretty close to what tsurime eyes are supposed to represent.

Comment: @RossRidge look i dont even like non non biyori i just saw the first episode and I dont really think a kid who gazes at flowers to the point of nearly missing a bus, talks with a monotonous voice, randomly shouts nyanpasu during class and thinks a tanuki is her pet is what you call the "serious type". Anyway the common trait of all of the aforementioned characters is the monotonous way of talking and that they nearly never smile

Comment: Like I said you need to update your question to make it more clear what you're talking about. Find characters that you're actually familiar with, from shows you actually liked enough to watch more than one episode, whose eyes actually are constantly like what you're asking about, and use them to illustrate your question. Mention all the specific character traits you think are associated with these kind of eyes in the question itself.

Comment: Akame (From Akame Ga Kill) sometimes has this kind of eyes : http://i.imgur.com/64hWiMq.png Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: it certainly has something to do with it, but this trope is used when the character is unimpressed or even disappointed about something 
(￢_￢) in a similar way to the sweat drop and other visual conventions whereas these characters are constantly like that

Comment: I think you are looking for something way too particular.

Comment: this eye ( [Terse](http://postimg.org/image/61vjgit8x/) ) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**"*Hanmoku*" (半目, half[-closed] eyes)** is drawn the same way or similarly to "*jitome*" (ジト目, staring eyes)](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E7%9B%AE), but is not identical in intent. "*Jitome*" is a facial expression where the person expresses negative feelings, which are mainly from among, but not limited to, the following: contempt/scorn, disbelief, distaste, resistance, appalled/scandalized (you can see Google's image search results for "jitome" [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E7%9B%AE&tbm=isch)). The difference between "*hanmoku*" and "*jitome*" is that "*hanmoku*" is used for characters who always have eyes drawn in this way regardless of whether or not they harbor any negative feelings at the moment. [Ichijō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pani_Poni_characters#Ichij.C5.8D) from *Pani Poni* and [Hiiragi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanamaru_Kindergarten#Kindergarten_students) from *Hanamaru Yōchien* are examples of "*hanmoku*" characters. Also, if you do a Google image search for ["*hanmoku*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%8D%8A%E7%9B%AE&tbm=isch), you find that, outside of anime, the word is used simply to describe having one's eyes half-closed for whatever reason (such as being half-asleep or not ready to be photographed).

["*Hosome*"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E7%B4%B0%E7%9B%AE) (細目) is similar to "*hanmoku*," but is a [squinting that can be applied to anime characters whose eyes always look closed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E7%B4%B0%E7%9B%AE%20%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1) even when the plot clearly portrays that their eyes are open and they are able to see just fine.

Extra Background:

The word "*jitome*" is derived from the onomatopoeia "*jito*" (じと), which means to "stare hard at." "*Jitto*" (じっと) is a similar word meaning to "stare without moving" or more generally "remain motionless" or do something "fixedly." "*Jitome*" has been used at least since 1978, where it was used in the screenplay for the film *[9-gatsu no Sora](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=7oFEAQAAIAAJ)* (『 九月の空 』), in which a parenthetical remark directed the actor to "*jitome de mite*" （ジト目で見て）. The script was published in 1979. In the 1980s, the word appeared in the shoujo light novel *[Oka no Ie no Mickey](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%98%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%B6%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC)* (『 丘の家のミッキー』) by Kumi Saori, published by Shuueisha's Bunko Cobalt Series.

Comment: This could be a Western analogue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGAu_DeKckI

Answer (score 3):

You're probably talking about jitome. (ジト目)

Unlike tsurime or tareme, (which are traits particular characters have,) it's more of a facial expression.

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment yet... adding to puzzlet's answer:

Jitome is "when the top of the eye is drawn with a flat line perpendicular to the rest of the eye. Used to effect a bored, expressionless, or scornful face."

This effect is frequently used with background characters that don't move or really add much except scenery to the current narrative, as the expression is usually neutral and doesn't influence the scene much.  In the particular example you used I'd say it's being used to show mild disbelief and/or disinterest.  If the character is always drawn that way, it's more of a personality trait of always showing disinterest in the world and what's happening around them.  Basically they're stand-offish or non-sociable.

See this wiki entry on an NSFW (the link itself is safe, just don't wander too far) site for more examples: https://danbooru.donmai.us/wiki_pages/27181